# Compare two dataframes row by row and add a row each time they are not equal

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to compare two dataframes row by row, let's say df1 with 4 rows and df2 with 3 rows :

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=c('a','b','c','d'),x2=c(1,2,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(x1=c('a','b','d'),x2=c(5,6,7))
```

I'd like to transform df2 by comparing it with df1 row by row : each time the value of row i in column1 for df2 is different from the value of row i in column1 for df1, I'd like to add a new row in df2 so that at the end of the loop, the two dataframes have the same number of rows and also the first columns are exactly the same.

It means that I would like df2 looks like this at the end of the comparison :

```
df2 <- data.frame(x1=c('a','b','c','d'),x2=c(5,6,0,7))
```

I've tried doing that with a loop but R returns an error

> Error in Ops.factor(df1[i, 1], df2[i, 1]) : 
>     les niveaux des facteurs diffèrent"

```
for (i in 1:length(df2)){
  if (df1[i,1]!=df2[i,1])
  {df1<- rbind(df1[1:i,],df2[i,],df1[i+1,])}
}
```

Comment: `data.frame(x1 = df1$x1 ,x2 = df2$x2[match(df1$x1, df2$x1)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a left join basically:

```
new_df2 <- merge(df1["x1"],df2,all.x=TRUE)
```

Then if you want `0` instead of `NA`

```
new_df2$x2[is.na(new_df2$x2)] <- 0

#   x1 x2
# 1  a  5
# 2  b  6
# 3  c  0
# 4  d  7
```